# Alternate Proof that for A, B disjoint, A compact and B closed there is positive distance between the sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Is my proof for this correct? I've seen the proof by contradiction that uses the triangle inequality, but this was the first proof that I came up with, and I'd like to test my understanding by asking if my proof is also correct. I'm uncertain of whether or not my claim that $\inf d(M_x, y) >0, \inf d(m_x,y) >0 $ is correct, or if my claim that $\inf d(x, y) = \inf\{ \inf d(M_x, y), \inf d(m_x, y) \}$ is correct.

### My Proof:

This is for a metric space $(X, d)$ with $A, B \subset X$ subsets of $X$, and $x \in A$, $y \in B$

$$A \mbox{ compact } \Rightarrow A \mbox{ bounded } \Rightarrow ^\exists M_x, m_x \: | \: M_x = \sup A, \: m_x = \inf A$$ Since $M_x$ and $m_x$ are upper and lower bounds, for some sequences $(x_n)_n \in A$, it is true that $$(x_n)_i \rightarrow M_x, (x_n)_i \rightarrow m_x$$ $$A \mbox{ compact } \Rightarrow A \mbox{ closed } \Rightarrow A \mbox{ contains its accumulation pts } \Rightarrow M_x, m_x \in A$$
$$A \cap B = \emptyset \Rightarrow M_x, m_x \notin B$$
Since $M_x$ and $m_x$ are not in $B$, we have $$\{\inf d(M_x, y) \: | \: y \in B\} > 0, \mbox{ and }\{\inf d(m_x, y) \: | \: y \in B\} > 0 $$By definition of $M_x$ and $m_x$, they are the closest possible points to any points in another set $S$ where $A \cap S = \emptyset$, so $$ \{ \inf d(x, y) \: | \: x \in A, \: y \in B \} = \inf \{ \inf d (M_x, y) \: | \: y \in B, \: \inf d(m_x, y) \: | \: y\in B\} > 0$$

So $$ d(A, B) = \{ \inf d(x, y) \: | \: x \in A, \: y \in B \} > 0$$

Comment: Is $A$ a subset of $\Bbb R$? If not, what do you mean by $\sup A$?

Comment: My bad. $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a general metric space $(X, d)$. I've edited the original post.

Comment: Unfortunately, you still have a problem: $\sup A$ doesn’t have any meaning in an arbitrary metric space, because the points of the space aren’t in general ordered in any way.

Comment: Ah, I see. So should I instead define $M_x$ such that for any $x_i, x_j \in A$, we have $d(x_i, x_j) < M_x$?

Comment: Yes, you could let $M_A=\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\}$, for instance; that’s actually the definition of the diameter of a set $A$ in a metric space, sometimes denoted by $\operatorname{diam}(A)$.